# php scandir loop order correction

Tags: php, directory, scandir

Please help with this php code:

```
<?php

function listFolderFiles($dir){
  static $level = 0;
  $level++;
  $ffs = scandir($dir);
  foreach($ffs as $ff){
        echo "<div id=\"datalist\">";

    if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
      if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
        $h_start = ($level < 6) ? "<h".($level+1). "class=\"multiple\">" : "<h6><div id=\"list_wrapper\">"; 
        $h_close = ($level < 6) ? "</h".($level+1)."> " : "</h6>"; 
        echo $h_start.$ff.$h_close; 
  echo '<ul class="multiple_columns">';

        listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
      } else {
        echo "<li><a href=\"$dir/$ff\">$ff</a></li>";
      }
    }
      echo '</ul></div>';
  }
  echo '</div>';
  $level--;
}

listFolderFiles('../Secure');

?>
```

I need the output directory to be organised in this manner:

```
   <div id="datalist">
      <h2 class="multiple">
      <h3> where applicable
         <div id="list_wrapper">
         <ul class="multiple_columns">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
         </ul>
         </div>
   </div>
```

Am not very familiar with php... as you can tell :) 
 Have tried different variations, but the output is always garbled. 
 Looking for some help in putting it in the right order. 
 Appreciate your inputs. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, I don't even understand what you're saying. What's wrong with your code exactly?

Comment: Hi Kemal Fadillah... sorry for not being clear. The code i have put up should generate a directory and sub directory list with all the files. The directory folders should appear as headings while files appear as links in un-ordered lists. This code does give me the list, but the output is garbled - it needs to follow the example i have given above. Hope that explains it better.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$h_start = ($level < 6) ? "<h".($level+1). "class=\"multiple\">" : "<h6><div id=\"list_wrapper\">";
```

with this

```
$h_start = ($level < 6) ? "<h".($level+1). " class=\"multiple\">" : "<h6><div id=\"list_wrapper\">";
```

your code generate h1class ,h2class ,... tag that's not corrert !

Comment: Hi afshin.. thanks for your reply. But the replacement you have suggested looks exactly like the code i've got. Can you explain what i should change?

Comment: Oh, i see... i will make the change and check. :)